# Devise Sign up not pulling fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Ok so I have installed devise as it is and I have my sign up page, but when I input stuff into it, it tells me it's empty and cannot be blank. I've validated presence and all that so I cannot understand what is happening. Please see the form below, but I also notice it's flashing Email/password cannot be blank twice...

Let me know what else you may need.

devise/registrations.html.erb

## Sign Up

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>



   <div><%= f.label :name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :name %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :profile_name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :profile_name%></div>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation%></div>
<br />
  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Updated: Log showing the following

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"JGpbRxL9lPqYh34mcvXSVby7rl3NPwt/YyTrmgqcx9E=", "user"=>{"name"=>"", "profile_name"=>"", "email"=>"", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
Unpermitted parameters: name, profile_name
```

Just so I understand this, why would name, profile_name be unpermitted, is this to do with attr_accessible?

**Solution. Even with protected_attributes installed you will still need to put the following in**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception



  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:name, :profile_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
  end
end
```

Comment: please go ahead and read about how to debug a rails application: http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a read of this.

Comment: That helped, see my log above.

Comment: cheers! it would be good if you add that edit as an answer and mark it resolved. that way others don't have to look into this any longer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems even with protected attributes you still need to place the following into your application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception



  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:name, :profile_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you explicitly permitting parameters in your controller?

This would be required in addition to configure_permitted_parameters

eg.

```
def post_params
   params.require(::sign_up).permit(:name, :profile_name, :email, :password)
end
```